# Exibir texto vindo consulta a banco em @Html.Actionlink()

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Bem, tenho o seguinte cenário:

Faço uma consulta no *banco de dados* e trago um `IEnumerable<>` para a `View`:

```
 <section class="container">
    <article class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <h3 style="background-color:orangered; margin:0; text-align:center;color:white;">@Html.ActionLink(item.Titulo, "MostraPublicacao", "Publicacao", new { id = item.PublicacaoId })</h3>     
                    <img src="~/Uploads/Imagens/teste.jpg" class="col-md-12 " style="padding:0;" />
                    <div>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Resumo);
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </article>
</section>
```

Sendo assim, o meu *TITTULO* é recebido por esta linha

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Resumo);
```

Preciso exibir o *texto* do resumo em um `@Html.ActionLink()` para ser um `link` afim de redirecionar para uma outra `View`, que **receberá o ID** deste Objeto como parâmetro

Uma imagem para tentar ilustrar melhor o problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolvo este problema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lugar do `@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Resumo)` apenas altere para algo como:

`@Html.ActionLin(item.resumo, "ACTION", "CONTROLLER", new{id = item.PUBLICACAOID})`

Desta forma, o texto será o resumo, mas o HTML gerado será algo como:

```
<a href="/CONTROLLER/ACTION/ID"> @item.titulo </a>
```